# SSH, VNC, HTTP(S), telnet... connection manager for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, vnc

I'm searching for a tool on Mac OS X, that is able to manage multiple and different connections. On Windows, there is a tool like this called [mRemote](http://www.mremote.org/wiki/).

Until now, I've been using the .ssh/config file, but I like the idea to not only have all ssh connections in one place, but also all "Web-Admins", VNC-connections,...

I found one tool called "Remoter" (on the app store), but there is only one screenshot which doesn't contain the nice tree-view like mRemote has it.

Does anybody of you know about a tool like this?

Comment: Been looking for this two. I came accross CoRD some time ago, but its RDC only. http://cord.sourceforge.net/